# How do I trigger the ascension/numbers cinematic at the beginning of Black Ops?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops

Before *Call of Duty: Black Ops*' start screen, there was a cinematic of a lady talking into a microphone.  She said the word "Ascension" followed by a series of numbers.

Now I don't want to know why they showed me that if it's anything plot-related, but I would like to know how I can make it happen again and where I can watch it online.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be available on youtube, in HD even:

Comment: that's the one, how do I trigger it?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried viewing it again by loading off a different save device and starting a new campaign session with no luck, it doesn't show that cinematic.

Since there's no config file like the PC, I would think that if you could go to System Settings > Memory > Save Device and delete all the files related to COD: Black Ops, or move them to a removable device, then start it back up, I would think it would play again. It seems like it's saved somewhere in a preference that can't be overridden that can be found.

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Sign in with a different account and it will play it again.

Answer (score 0):

Fired up the game yesterday, didn't hit any buttons and that video played. Not sure what triggered it, so i restarted, and the video didn't play. Did the same today and it played again. Looks like it plays after the Treyarch/Activision logos if you don't hit any buttons and only one time a day from what I can tell.